# Java not found by Elasticsearch on Centos 6.6, all path variables are set and working

Tags: java, linux, elasticsearch, vagrant, centos6

I recently spun up a vagrant server and wanted to get Elasticsearch going on it. So, I installed Oracle Java and ES on a "chef/Centos-6.6" vagrant cloud VM. I set my Java path using a shell script in "etc/profile.d".

Here is my provisioning script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
yum -y update

wget -O /opt/jdk-7u67-linux-x64.tar.gz --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header   "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2F; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u67-b01/jdk-7u67-linux-x64.tar.gz"
tar xzf /opt/jdk-7u67-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/
touch /etc/profile.d/java.sh
echo "export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_67" >> /etc/profile.d/java.sh
echo "export JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_67/jre" >> /etc/profile.d/java.sh
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk1.7.0_67/bin:/opt/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/bin" >> /etc/profile.d/java.sh

rpm --import http://packages.elasticsearch.org/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch
REPO="[elasticsearch-1.3]
name=Elasticsearch repository for 1.3.x packages
baseurl=http://packages.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/1.3/centos
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://packages.elasticsearch.org/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch
enabled=1"
echo "$REPO" > /etc/yum.repos.d/elasticsearch.repo
yum install -y elasticsearch
```

The install all goes fine. However, when I run "sudo service elasticsearch start" I get:

```
which: no java in (/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin)
```

but if I "echo $PATH" for home user i get:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/opt/jdk1.7.0_67/bin:/opt/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/bin:/home/vagrant/bin
```

and for root user $PATH i get:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/opt/jdk1.7.0_67/bin:/opt/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/bin
```

and "echo $JAVA_HOME" i get:

```
/opt/jdk1.7.0_67
```

if I run "which java" i get:

```
/opt/jdk1.7.0_67/bin/java
```

and if I run "java" it shows up with the man page.

How is it that elasticsearch is not looking in my path for java? Why is it only looking in the default Centos path? What am i missing here?

Comment: Don't know what you're missing, but nothing that some `ln -s /opt/jdk1.7.0_67/bin/java /bin/java` can't fix, I guess.

Comment: Thank you, that does work, I didn't think about making a symbolic link. Its still troubling that it doesn't work

Comment: I'm aware this is not the academic solution you're looking for, but until you find it out, this will unlock you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of your problem is probably that init scripts (Elastic init script in this case) don't see most environment variables (eg `JAVA_HOME`, `JRE_HOME`, etc).

If you look at the [ElasticSearch init script](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/deb/init.d/elasticsearch#L22), you will see that `PATH` variable is set explicitly in that init script and `JAVA_HOME` is determined by looping through predefined set of possible locations:

```
JDK_DIRS="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7-oracle-x64 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/ /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-armhf /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/ /usr/lib/jvm/default-java"
```

So you could put your Java installation for example to `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7-oracle-x64` directory and the init script should pick it up.

**Update**

Looking at the init script I noticed that you can set `JAVA_HOME` in `/etc/default/elasticsearch` to skip looping through the predefined JDK locations as mentioned above ([Source](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/deb/init.d/elasticsearch#L46)).

Comment: Awesome, this was driving me crazy. From what I read it seemed like "/etc/profile.d" would set these variables globally, i guess this is the exception. thanks for clearing this up

Comment: @patrickbarker `/etc/profile.d/` does indeed set variables globally. But if you look at `man service` it mentions that it strips almost all environment variables so that the service can run in most predictable environment. I believe that if the service starts during system startup these variables might not be set yet, so it's probably best that the script does not depend on them. But I'm not 100% sure about this last part :) Maybe some Linux expert could confirm that. Anyways, I'm glad it worked for you :)

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt, both links to Github are broken.